# Variable type with MoveFile() in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So I am trying to move a file that the user specifies by using cin and MoveFile(). But the thing is MoveFile() parameters take LPCTSTR variables but cin doesnt take those variable types can anyone help me with a conversion from a char myChars[] table to a LPCTSTR variable? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LPCTSTR is a `typedef`. It's actually another type: It's a **l**ong **p**ointer to a **c**onst `TCHAR` **str**ing. Or, in other words, it's a `const TCHAR*`.

A `TCHAR` is also a `typedef`, but it's either a `char` or a wide character, depending on whether your project is using Unicode or ASCII. They usually default to Unicode.

You can use `MoveFileA` to force ASCII. Then, a `LPCTSTR` is literally a `const char*`.